# Creating custom object from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js

I have an array with below elements. I  am trying to create an object from the array

```
var arr = [
  'find({ qty: { $lt: 20 } } )',
  'limit(5)',
  'skip(0)'
]
```

Below is my code. where I am getting only values as the output. Any help on this will be helpful

```
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        var res = arr[i].search(/\(/ig)
        if (res!= -1) {
            var result = arr[i].split("(");
            result = result[1].slice(0, -1))
        }
    }
```

**Expected Output**

```
 {
      "action": "find",
      "value": "{ qty: { $lt: 20 } }",
      "limit": 5,
      "skip": 0
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`match` is better than `split` for this kind of stuff

```js
var arr = [
  'find({ qty: { $lt: 20 } } )',
  'limit(5)',
  'skip(0)'
]


var obj = {};

arr.forEach(function(x, n) {
  var m = x.match(/(\w+)\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)/);
  if(n == 0) {
    obj.action = m[1];
    obj.value = m[2];
  } else
    obj[m[1]] = m[2];
    
});

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(obj,0,3));
```

Comment: Thanks all for helping me. Now Im getting the expected output. Is it possible to make the value as Object not as string ({ qty: { $lt: 20 } }).
{
      "action": "find",
      "value": "{ qty: { $lt: 20 } }",
      "limit": 5,
      "skip": 0
    }

Comment: @mish Your code is working buthas one major flaw. {
   "action": "find",
   "value": "{ qty: { $lt: 20 } }",
   "limit": "5",
   "skip": "0"
}
Values are getting converted to string. Eg. "limit":5

Comment: @user4324324: I didn't answer - whose code are you referring to?

Comment: @mish My mistake. I apologize for it. :)

Answer (score 2):

see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/naeemshaikh27/qcpr43dn/2/)

Just check if element is first in array, if yes, set action and value keys to splitted array, else just assign splitted values to key and value respectively

```js
var arr = [
  'find({ qty: { $lt: 20 } } )',
  'limit(5)',
  'skip(0)'
]
var result = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var res = arr[i].split("(")
  console.log(res)
  result[res[0]] = res[1].split(')')[0]
}

document.write(JSON.stringify(result))
```