# Directly attach the link to the sentence

Tags: javascript, json

[This is the link to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29026688/creating-custom-object-from-array), where I was forming the array and creating the custom object.

Here is my code where I am splitting the string and forming the object.

```
var obj = {};
var string = 'db["employee"].findOne({"EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID": 100, "EMP.EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Mark"},{"CITY":1,"code":1}).limit(5).skip(0)';
var newString1 = string.split("({", 2);
var str = newString1[0].split(/[\.\[]/, 3);
obj.action = str[2];
```

I am not able to split rest of the fields inside the string and form the object like below.

```
{
    "action": "findOne",
    "value": '[{"EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID": 100, "EMP.EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Mark"},{"CITY":1,"code":1}]',
    "limit": 5,
    "skip": 0
}
```

Comment: "action":"findOne" the  left hand side is the key.and the right hand side is the value..you need to insert them in json too

Comment: @Hatem Ahmed No. I want just the object.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Completing whole object formation, but please try it yourself next.

```
var string = 'db["employee"].findOne({"EMP.EMPLOYEE_ID": 100, "EMP.EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Mark"},{"CITY":1,"code":1}).limit(5).skip(0)';
var action = string.split(']')[1].split('(')[0];  
var value = '[' + string.split('findOne(')[1].split(')')[0] + ']';
var limit = parseInt(string.split('limit(')[1].split(')')[0]);
var skip = parseInt(string.split('skip(')[1].split(')')[0]);

var obj = {
    action: action,
    value: value,
    limit: limit,
    skip: skip
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me how to get the object which I have mentioned in question from the below string 'db.bios.find().limit(5).sort({name:1})'